# Maximizing the size on a data type in C# and SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have developed a huge solution using C# and the ASP.NET framework and I made a silly mistake in the beginning when I had defined the variable `Login_id` as `int` in C# and SQL Server. I was thinking it can hold up to the maximum of 10 digits but unfortunately it is taking up to max. range 2,147,483,647 and my maximum value is 7,999,999,999.

My issue now: it is difficult to change it to (long int) and (bigint) as the table is linked to many other tables as foreign key I will have to change in database and in the code.

Is there any simple way of fixing this?

Comment: `alter table mytable alter column mycolumn bigint not null;`

Comment: **(1)** drop all the foreign keys, **(2)** modify column type to `BIGINT` in main table and any related child tables, **(3)** re-create all the foreign keys

Comment: @VDWWD this wont work unless to disable the constraints because it is primary key and in front end also to edit again all things

Comment: @marc_s it is linked to more than 20 tables again it is going to take more time, lets see if any developer has simple method

Comment: If using an ORM, it can probably generate scripts for you. If not, and you have redgate or something, it can also. Otherwise, I think the quickest way is to just write a sql script to do it manually.

Comment: @Nikki9696 you are right changing in script is better choice also lets see others suggestions

Comment: You have 2.1 billion ID records? Is your seed incremental by 1 or something larger!?

Comment: no identity in that , it is just primary key based on local id

Comment: What datatype is the local ID field? Depending on its datatype you could run into this issue again even after updating the int.

Comment: it is a number of 10 digits